# Use a regex in a Tesseract dictionary file

Tags: regex, dictionary, tesseract

I am currently using the Tesseract OCR, and wondering if it is possible to add regular expressions to the dictionary file.

According to my assumptions every word found by Tesseract is being checked against a dictionary to enhance the accuracy of the results.

Now I want to search for example for a string of 8 digits, then I would like to be able to add such a regex to the 'dictionary', which ensures that no letters will be among those 8 digits.

Is this possible? If so, how?

I only found this so far, and we are on 3.02 currently: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bazaar](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc) matching pattern in Tesseract.

Comment: Will this work in combination with a dictionary file? And I will definitely look into this as this seems to be the correct answer!

Comment: The bazaar config loads the user dictionary but not the system dictionary, but sure, you can change and try.

Comment: Big bummer though that it doesn't load the system dictionary, as I'd like the regex matching as an addition to the system dictionary (and possibly user dictionary)

Comment: this link is broken